# how can I dynamically create an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to dynamically create an array of numbers from 1 to 100 which contains 4 arrays each containing 5 arrays containing 5 numbers. example:

```
[
[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24,25]],
[[26,...,30],[31,...,35],[36,...,40],[41,..,45],[46,...,50]],
[[51,...55],[56,...60],[61,...,65],[66,...,70],[71,..,75]],
[[76,...,80],[81,...,85],[86,...,90],[91,...95],[96,...100]]
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Do you know how to get from the number to the index of the inner and outer array?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. My approach: first create an array of numbers that increment from 1 to 100. Then, use `reduce()` to group them into chunks of 20. Finally, use `.map()` and `.reduce()` together to group them into smaller chunks of 5.

```js
const chunk = (values, chunkSize) => 
   values.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const lastGroup = acc[acc.length - 1];
    const isFull = lastGroup.length === chunkSize;
    if (isFull) { return [...acc, [val]]; }
    return [...acc.slice(0,-1), [...lastGroup, val]];
  }, [[]]);

const list = Array.from({ length: 100 }, (val, i) => i + 1);
const chunks1 = chunk(list, 20);
const chunks2 = chunks1.map(ch => chunk(ch, 5));

console.log(chunks2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function chunk (items, size) {  
  const chunks = []
  items = [].concat(...items)

  while (items.length) {
    chunks.push(
      items.splice(0, size)
    )
  }

  return chunks
}
```

and then

```
chunk(Array.from({length: 100}, (_, i) => i + 1),5)
```